# Solution of differential equation on specific point python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I have a differential equation:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
   k = 0.3
   dydt = -k * y
   return dydt

# initial condition
y0 = 5

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,10)
t1=2
# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)
```

And I want to evaluate the solution of this differential equation on two different points. For example I want y(t=2) and  y(t=3).

**I can solve the problem in the following way:**

Suppose that you need y(2). Then you, define

```
t = np.linspace(0,2)
```

and just print

```
print y[-1]
```

In order to get the value of y(2). However I think that this procedure is slow, since I need to do  the same again in order to calculate y(3), and if I want another point I need to do same again. So there is some faster way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the value of y(2) as starting condition for y(3) so you only need to integrate from t=2 to t=3 and not again from t=0 to t=3?

Comment: Or just integrate in one go to the highest t you need. Apparently the resulting `y` contains all intermediate values.

Comment: How do you print the intermediate values? I get one array for the values of y, but I don't know how to print the specific values that I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't this just:

```
y = odeint(model, y0, [0, 2, 3])[1:]
```

i.e. the [third parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) just specifies the values of `t` that you want back.

as an example of printing the results out, we'd just follow the above with:

```
print(f'y(2) = {y[0,0]}')
print(f'y(3) = {y[1,0]}')
```

which gives me:

```
y(2) = 2.7440582441900494
y(3) = 2.032848408317066
```

which seems the same as the anytical solution:

```
5 * np.exp(-0.3 * np.array([2,3]))
```

Comment: @Cruz Did you try `print(y[0])`, `print(y[2])`, `print(y[3])`?!

Comment: You can easily check that y[2]/=y(2) and y[3]/=y(2). That is the reason because I ask. The analytical solution of this  ODE is y(x)=5* Exp^(-0.3 x).

Comment: How do you print y(2), and y(3)?

Comment: @Cruz I'd suggest following a general Python tutorial if you're struggling with printing things like that

Comment: This could be a problem with my computer. If I use some online compiler I get what you say, but if I use my computer I get another result.

Comment: You could also use `t=[0,2,3]; y=odeint(model,y0,t); for k in range(3): print(f'y({t[k]}) = {y[k,0]}')` with the unshortened odeint result. These f-strings or string interpolation however only work from python 3.6 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can get exactly what you want if you use `solve_ivp` with the dense-output option

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(t,y):
   k = 0.3
   dydt = -k * y
   return dydt

# initial condition
y0 = [5]

# solve ODE
res = solve_ivp(model,[0,10],y0,dense_output=True)
y = lambda t: res.sol(t)[0]

for t in [2,3,3.4]:
    print(f'y({t}) = {y(t)}')
```

with the output

```
y(2) = 2.743316182689662
y(3) = 2.0315223673200338
y(3.4) = 1.802238620366918
```

Comment: not noticed `dense_output=True` for `solve_ivp`.  think I've always known where I wanted solutions, but it looks like a useful tool!

Comment: It is of questionable usefulness. Keeping the interpolation polynomials for high-dimensional systems can rapidly exhaust the memory. The required density of integration node-points is dynamically generated and can be surprising, esp. when changing tolerances. Without "dense output", the values at the given sampling points are evaluated using these same polynomials, but their data is discarded/reused in the next step, so that the memory profile is controllable. If you want to work directly with the polynomials, it is often better to use the stepper classes directly in a custom time loop.